# Tabbed bar controller icon - cannot display png

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, tabbed

I am trying to get a 31x31 png icon to display without much luck.

I have lost count of the different settings I have applied to numerous copies of the icon.
Used all combinations when saving as a PNG from within Photoshop.
Even tried downloading an ICC color profile for the iphone - again no luck.

Can anyone tell me how the set up the photoshop file and save it so I can successfully get png files to show on the tabbed bar?

Answer (score 0):

Is your PNG file part of your project file?  You'll need to add it to the project as well for it to get copied over to the Simulator/Device as part of the bundle.

Also, since the Tab Bar images use the PNG transparency - not the graphics themselves - to render, can you double check that your image is not 100% non-transparent?  Otherwise it would appear as all black.  What is your image's background in photoshop?

Comment: Yes def part of the project file - the frustrating thing is that I downloaded a png icon from a resource site on the web and it displays immediately once placed in the project and simulated.

I just cannot figure why my png files are not displaying :-(

Comment: Image background is transparent - with a black icon (speaker)

Comment: Can you send me the file or put it on a public dropbox? :)